# Firebase Audience - How to fix custom audience not showing iOS data

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-analytics

My custom audience is not showing data when filtered for iOS. It only has data for android. Any ideas where the issue may be?

My firebase project has multiple apps within it, both iOS and Android (they are all running the same backend).

Using the new Audience builder, I have created a custom audience to group the iOS and Android versions of the same app together using the Dimensions > User Properties > Stream variable (this is the Bundle ID for iOS or Package name for Android which in this case are the same value).

```
e.g. com.domainname.appname
```

[Image of Stream property selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOVB0.png)

However despite having logged events from over 10 iOS devices, and the audience having been set up over a week, I am only seeing users appearing in it from android.

I'm unsure if the issue is with my audience definition in Firebase or a missed connection to the iOS app version.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: OK, we've launched our app now and I am still having issues with this as iOS users are not appearing in the Audience. The filter for **Stream** on the dashboard lists the streams individually by platform even with the same name, but in **Audience** creation, it only lists a single version. I've tried adding a Platform filter in Audience creation but it still doesn't detect iOS users, only android.

Comment: Have you been able to fix it?